# Get value with #tag from input, when the input field might not exist

Tags: angular, input, ngfor

I have a ngFor loop that fill a table for me. In this table, there can be tables containing more data.

Some of the elements being filled have one mandatory set of input, from which I can already obtain the value like this:

```
<table *ngIf="boolean">
...
    <tr>
        <td><input #textInput type=text value="{{defaultValue}}"/></td>
    </tr>
...
    <button (click)="save1(stuff, textInput.value)">Save</button>
</table>
```

However, in some case I have two set of input, and one or both can be present.

```
<table  *ngIf="boolean">
...
    <tr *ngIf="boolean2">
        <td><input #textInput type=text value="{{defaultValue}}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="boolean3">
        <td><input #secondTextInput type=text value="{{defaultValue}}"/></td>
    </tr>
...
    <button (click)="save2(stuff, textInput.value, secondTextInput.value)">Save</button>
</table>
```

I tried using the `?` in case the value doesn't exist but it doesn't work. So far I can only get `null` values. If I receive a null value if the field doesn't exist, this is not a problem, I'll just filter it. But even if both exists, I can't get any value from them.

The second code gives me an error:

> _co.value is undefined

Same thing if I replace one of the value with 0.

Comment: I think you have to use different  template reference variables for each row. For now you use #textInput and #secondTextInput for all rows, that doesn't look correct.

Comment: @slesh well without the ngIf, it works correctly, I can get the value of each field individually,.

Comment: Try pass not value propery, but element itself, and then inside save2 method *?* will work. I.e. <button (click)="save2(stuff, textInput, secondTextInput)">Save</button>.


let text1 = textInput1 ? textInput1.value : '';
let text2 = textInput2 ? textInput2.value : '';

Comment: @slesh No more error, but what is the type of the element I'm passing ? How do I access the value in my *.ts file ?

Comment: I'd suggest assign any. It should work

Comment: [This](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) one looks good

Comment: @slesh Ok, but how do I get the value once in my component ? myElement.value doesn't seem to work

Comment: Do you access to .value propery of element:ElementRef or native element:any? For ElementRef try element. nativeElement.value, for native - just element.value.